# K-Means Clustering of random numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, plot, k-means

I have a program that generates 10 fixed points and 3 random points when run. I would like the 10 fixed points to use K-means clustering but don't know where to begin. My code is below

```
function TESTING (re_point)

%***********************NOTE*************************************
% if re_point = 0 [default]
%     points generated for xtemp and y_temp remain fixed
% if re_point = 1
%     new points are generated for x_temp and y_temp

% Variable definitions for tags and figure window
persistent xtemp ytemp hFig

% Initialisiation of re_point
if nargin<1
    re_point = 0; % If 0, the points are fixed, if 1 they move
end

A1 = 30; % area defined as 30 X 30 grid
N = 10;
R = 3; % 3 readers
s = rng; % fixed tags does not change position when simulated repatedly
rng(s)

if (isempty(xtemp) && isempty(xtemp)) || re_point == 1
    % Generate x and y position of tags 
    xtemp = A1*rand(1,N);
    ytemp = A1*rand(1,N);
end
if isempty(hFig)
    hFig = figure;
end

% Generate x and y position of red points 
xtemp_2 = A1*rand(1,R);
ytemp_2 = A1*rand(1,R);

% plot data
plot(xtemp,ytemp,'.',xtemp_2,ytemp_2,'rs','LineWidth',1,'MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerSize',14);

% Labelling of the red markers
for iter = 1:numel(xtemp_2)
    text(xtemp_2(iter),ytemp_2(iter), num2str(iter),...
        'FontSize',8,'HorizontalAlignment','center',...
        'Color','White','FontWeight','bold');
end

grid on
hold off
axis([0 A1 0 A1])

% Tag formatting
xoffset = 0;
yoffset = -1;
fsize = 8;
temp_str = mat2cell(num2str([xtemp(:) ytemp(:)], '(%.2f,%.2f)'), ones(1,N));
text(xtemp+xoffset, ytemp+yoffset, temp_str,'fontsize', fsize)

% distance function calculator
cDistance = distanceCalc()

    function S = distanceCalc
        S = size(numel(xtemp),numel(xtemp_2));
        for ri = 1:numel(xtemp)
            for fi = 1:numel(xtemp_2)
                S(ri,fi) = pdist([xtemp(ri),ytemp(ri);...
                            xtemp_2(fi),ytemp_2(fi)],...
                            'euclidean');
            end
        end
    end

end
```

This particular snippet from the block above generates the 10 fixed points that need to be clustered

```
if (isempty(xtemp) && isempty(xtemp)) || re_point == 1
        % Generate x and y position of tags 
        xtemp = A1*rand(1,N);
        ytemp = A1*rand(1,N);
    end
```

Comment: your question is unclear... is this about how to use kmeans in matlab? If so see http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html

Comment: Yes its in matlab, I mentioned it in the title. I've seen the mathworks documentation and couldn't understand how to implement it  so I came here for assistance.

Comment: I posted an answer below but the simplest answer to this question is to look at the very clear examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear at all from your question what you want to do with `kmeans`, for instance how many clusters are you looking for? I recommend looking at the first example in the [MATLAB ref guide](http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html)

For your data you can try e.g.

```
X = [xtemp(:) ytemp(:)];
Nclusters = 3;
[idx,C] = kmeans(X,Nclusters);
```

For plotting something like the following should work:

```
figure, hold on
plot(X(idx==1,1),X(idx==1,2),'b*')
plot(X(idx==2,1),X(idx==2,2),'g*')
plot(X(idx==3,1),X(idx==3,2),'r*')
```

to get started. This will attempt to classify your random points into 3 clusters. The cluster into which each point has been classified is defined in `idx`.

Comment: I wanted to put the data into Nclusters which you've helped me with, then colour code individual clusters if possible while highlighting the centroids. Do you have any suggestions or should I refer to the documentation? Thanks for your help and you've put me on the right path.

Comment: @Duanne The centroids are in C... for color coding there are lots of examples out there (and your own code suggests you should know how to do this?) but I added one way...

Comment: Just finished the code. I did the colour coding in another way, it was easier than I made it out to be. Thanks